# Ver fechas que hay entre dos fechas Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hola quisiera saber como ver las fechas que hay entre dos fechas,

es decir yo tengo un campo que es fechaInicial y otro que se llama fechaFin, ahora lo que quiero averiguar las fechas que hay entre esas dos.

---

estaba intentando de esta forma pero no me devuelve datos

```
WITH DateRange AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Fecha_Krdx) AS Date
    from V_Kardex_Detalle
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Fecha_Krdx) < Fecha_Out and Id_empleado='E-00003'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Fecha_Krdx)
    FROM V_Kardex_Detalle
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Fecha_Krdx) < Fecha_Out and Id_empleado='E-00003'
)
SELECT Date
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: usa WHERE ColumnName BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31' ...

Comment: queres que sql invente todas las fechas del medio?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que trataste o investigaste!, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La solución a esta pregunta, sin usar recursión, tiene tres *pasos*.

- Primero saber la cantidad de días que hay entre las dos fechas, usando la función `datediff()`
- Luego, generar una serie de números consecutivos, lo suficientemente larga como para cubrir el número de días que hay entre las fechas
- Luego es ir sumando a la fecha inicial los números de días obtenidos en el segundo paso, hasta llegar a la fecha final, usando la función `dateadd()`.

Para la segunda parte, hay varias formas de hacerlo; yo últimamente uso alguna tabla del diccionario de datos que tenga muchas filas y la función `row_number()` para obtener los números consecutivos. Esto por simplicidad de la consulta y porque las tablas del diccionario de datos suelen mantenerse *en caliente*, con lo que se genera una respuesta bastante rápida.

Por ejemplo:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n
  from sys.all_columns
```

Esta consulta suele devolver más de 10,000 filas en una base de datos típica en SQL Server 2019. Eso nos da suficientes *días* para cubrir más de 27 años de diferencia entre las fechas. Si necesitas más días, puedes hacer join entre la misma tabla o entre varias, y si usualmente necesitas muchos menos, puedes usar una tabla más pequeña.

Poniendo las piezas juntas, tendríamos algo como:

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20220101';
declare @FechaFin date = '20251231';

declare @numDias int = datediff(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin);

with
Numeros as (
select top (@numDias + 1) row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 n
  from sys.all_columns
)
select DATEADD(day, n, @FechaIni) Fecha
  from Numeros
```

Que nos devuelve:

```
Fecha
----------
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
2022-01-05
2022-01-06
...
2025-12-27
2025-12-28
2025-12-29
2025-12-30
2025-12-31

(1461 rows affected)
```

Como puedes observar, el listado incluye la fecha inicial y final. Si solo quieres los días intermedios, sin incluir, considero que te resultará trivial ajustar la consulta, además de ser un ejercicio interesante.

Una vez se ha comprendido el proceso, puede escribirse como una sola consulta, para legar al mismo resultado, por ejemplo

```
declare @FechaIni date = '20220101';
declare @FechaFin date = '20251231';

select top (datediff(day, @FechaIni, @FechaFin) + 1) 
       DATEADD(day, row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1, @FechaIni) Fecha
  from sys.all_columns;
```

---

**Edición**: Luego de la edición de la pregunta, veo que los datos que quieres procesar vienen de una tabla. Para aplicar la solución propuesta, puedes hacer un *cross apply* entre el registro de la tabla que quieres procesar y la tabla del diccionario de datos para generar números consecutivos, por ejemplo:

```
select   Fecha_Krdx
       , Fecha_Out
       , DATEADD(day, Num.N, Fecha_Krdx) Fecha
  from v_kardex_detalle
       cross apply (select top (DATEDIFF(Day, Fecha_Krdx, Fecha_Out) + 1) 
                           row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 n 
                      from sys.all_columns
                   ) Num
 where id_empleado = 'E-00003'
```

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2023-01-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2023-01-11';

WITH DateRange AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate) AS Date
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date) < @endDate
)
SELECT Date
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Genera:

```
Date
2023-01-02
2023-01-03
2023-01-04
2023-01-05
2023-01-06
2023-01-07
2023-01-08
2023-01-09
2023-01-10
```

De forma predeterminada, SQL Server limita el número de recursiones a 100. Sin embargo, al utilizar `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` al final de la query, puedes pasar de largo de este límite y permitir un número ilimitado de recursión, considero que como se desconoce el número de fechas iniciales y finales, ese cero está justificado.

Por cierto, lo que estás viendo como `WITH DateRange AS ...` es un Common Table Expression (CTE), lo utilicé para generar la lista de todos los días desde el día inicial hasta el día final.

Mayor información en la documentación oficial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Gracias ahorita lo aplico